# How to append a random or arbitrary column to data frame [R]

Tags: r, dplyr

Hear me out. Consider an arbitrary case where the new column's elements do not require any information from other columns (which I frustrates base $ and mutate assignment), and not every element in the new column is the same. Here is what I've tried:

```
df$rand<-rep(sample(1:100,1),nrow(df))
unique(df$rand)
[1] 58
```

and rest assured, `nrow(df)>1`. I think the correct solution might have to do with an apply function?

Comment: Do you want one random number repeated many times or `nrow(df)` many of random numbers?

Comment: nrow(df) many PRN's

Comment: Next time, just use `?sample` and `?rep`. Also, try to just run the code separately in the command line (running `sample(1:100, 1)` should have already shown you that your code was wrong).

Comment: @Laterow not necessarily, such an approach just doesn't conform with the vectorized paradigm of R. technically, shouldn't it be possible? What if I'm using a function that can only return a single int? However, in this case you're right, obviously supplying '1' as an argument totally misses the point of the sample function

Comment: @MikePalmice This has nothing to do with whether it conforms with the vectorized paradigm. You told `sample` to sample `1:100` only once. That's what it did. `rep` simply repeats what's in the first argument `nrow(df)` number of times. In this case, that one sample you specified. The vectorized paradigm still holds, try:  `df$rand = sample(1:100,1)` This gives the same result as `df$rand<-rep(sample(1:100,1),nrow(df))`

Comment: In defence of @MikePalmice, `rep` is described as '**Replicate** Elements (...)' (my emphasis), which could be interpreted as 'replicate `sample(1:100, 1)` nrow(df) times.', i.e. repeat the expression nrow(df) time, thus repeating the sampling.

Comment: helpful discussion. thanks for the clarification all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code repeats one single random number `nrow(df)` times. Try instead:

```
df$rand<-sample(1:100, nrow(df))
```

This samples *without replacement* from `1:100` `nrow(df)` times. Now this would give you an error if `nrow(df)>100` because you would run out of numbers from `1:100` to sample. To make sure you don't get this error, you can instead sample *with replacement*:

```
df$rand<-sample(1:100, nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
```

If, however, you don't want any random numbers to repeat but would also like to prevent the error, you can do something like this:

```
df$rand<-sample(1:nrow(df), nrow(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand this correctly ,I think this is pretty easily doable in dplyr or data.table .

for e.g dplyr soln on iris

```
iris%>%mutate(sample(n()))
```